# Change sorting order with parameters

Tags: scala, sorting

I tried to create an output for my movie list with different sorting order (depending on the parameter I type in), but the parameter doesn't work.
Error: Value sorting is not a member of Scala.Movie

```
def printResult(list: List[Movie], sorting : String) = {
  val movieList = list.filter(element => element.isInstanceOf[Movie])
  if (movieList.length > 0) 
  {
    val resultSize = chooseResultSize()
    val sizedList = movieList.filter(element => movieList.indexOf(element) < resultSize)
    val formtLength = sizedList.map(_.title.length).max + 9
    val printPattern = "%-" + formtLength + "s"

    println(s"\n$printPattern %-9s %-9s %-9s".format("Title", "Year", "Votes", "Rating"))

    for (movie <- ((for (film <- sizedList) yield film.asInstanceOf[Movie]).sortBy(_.sorting).reverse)) println(s"$printPattern %-9s %-9d %-9.1f".format(movie.title.trim, movie.year, movie.votes, movie.rating))
  } 
  else println("Sorry - no matches found!")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortBy` function waits from you a function `(Scala.Movie) => B`. So, you can't just pass a String value that indicates what field you want to sort by, you have to pass a function.

```
val movies = for (movie <- for (film <- sizedList) yield film.asInstanceOf[Movie]) yield movie
val sortedMovies = (sorting match {
    case "byYear" => movies.sortBy(_.year)
    case "byVotes" => movies.sortBy(_.votes)
    case _ => movies.sortBy(_.title)
}).reverse
sortedMovies foreach(movie => println(s"$printPattern %-9s %-9d %-9.1f".format(movie.title.trim, movie.year, movie.votes, movie.rating)))
```

Comment: @user3673445 you can mark it as resolved as well :) you are welcome.